# How to update array in C using pattern without loop, memcpy with pattern

Tags: c

**Optimization question**, on CPU using C (latest gcc/clang). I know how to use shaders, I do not need them in this task.

**I have:**

```
size_t texture_size = width * height * 4 * sizeof(uint8_t);
uint8_t *texture = malloc(texture_size);
```

or

```
uint8_t texture[width * height * 4]
```

this *texture* is `[width][height][4<rgba>]` image that I send to GPU in my Vulkan app(using Vulkan API)

final ussage of *texture* is `memcpy(to_gpu_mem, texture, texture_size);`

**I need:**

make 0 every `<blue>`(is index 2 in array) pixel of texture, so its:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        texture[((i * width + j) * 4 + 2) * sizeof(uint8_t)]=0;
    }
}
```

I do it using loop, and it work fine when I use only single image not big size.

*I do need update it almost every frame, in real time, not pregenerated data.*

So question is - **how to update array-data by "some pattern" in C, not using loop?**

The final array must look like single array with that order of data.

Comment: one loop? `for (k=0;k<height*width;k+=4*sizeof(uint8_t)) texture[k+2] = 0;`

Comment: I think your question is "how do I change lots of memory without it being slow." There is no special way, although it's important to write cache-friendly code (for example, swapping the `i` and `j` loops would be bad). Compile with -O2 if you're not already

Comment: *"how to update array-data by "some pattern" in C, not using loop?"* - you can't. You're working on a CPU, not a GPU. You can parallelize the matrix initialization using multiple threads but that's it. Other than that, just compile with `-O3 -ftree-vectorize -march=native`.

Comment: You mention shaders, and if it's possible modifying the shader you're using to zero out the B channel may be a _lot_ faster.

Comment: I can't think of a reasonable way to do this without a loop.  Any of the memory setting functions are going to be useless since you have specific memory bytes in the array.  @pmg probably has the best response.

Comment: I see thanks for answers.

Comment: You can create pointers for each "color" location in memory., i.e. `uint_8* RED = texture; uint_8* GREEN = texture + (width * height); uint_8* BLUE = GREEN + (width * height)`.  Then you can use the ipp libraries (a Vector Math Library) to perform your array processing.

Comment: @jiveturkey maybe I dont get it
my texture data is [r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a....etc]
when you example with pointer logic is [r,r,r,r,r.... g,g,g,g,g.... b,b,b,b,b... a,a,a,a....] if I understand correctly

Comment: My apologies, you'd have to restructure your array as `[4][width][height]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on comments, look like modern gcc/clang can not do that

so I think best solution is: (CUDA and OpenCL are way too slow)

1. use [Intel SPMD Program Compiler](https://github.com/ispc/ispc) that can do same logic as CUDA/shaders but on CPU
2. or use AMD integrated video card that has [VK_AMD_device_coherent_memory](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_AMD_device_coherent_memory.html) and use shader

I think this is answer my question.